# Inconsistent color output from `ls` command

Tags: linux, command-line, ls, colors

I teach an Intro to UNIX/Linux course at a local college and one of my students asked the following question:

*Why are some of the files in my directory colored white and others are gray? Are the white ones the ones I created today and the gray are existing files?*

As I looked into this I first thought the answer would be in the `LS_COLORS` variable, but further investigation revealed that the color listings were different when using the `-l` switch versus the `-al` switch with the `ls` command. See the following screen shots:

[image: using ls -l the file named '3' shows as white]

[image: using the -al switch the same file shows a gray]

Using `ls -l` the file named '3' shows as white but using the `-al` switch the same file shows a gray.

Is this a bug in ls or does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Wrt your question title: such coloring has nothing to do with the `ls` command itself.

Comment: FWIW, the closest you can get to this by messing with LS_COLORS is `LS_COLORS='rs=0;1' ls -l`, but it looks very different.

Comment: @Drew You only know that after investigating the problem. Obviously `ls` can change the color of its output.

Comment: @pipe: Nah, I know that from long before there was color. It *need not* provide color, even if recent versions of `ls` *can* provide color. ;-)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It looks as if your prompt-string (**`$PS1`**) is setting the bold attribute on characters to make the colors nicer, and not *unsetting* it.  The output from **`ls`** doesn't know about this, and ***does*** unset bold.  So after the first color output of **`ls`**, everything looks dimmer.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Last color change in $PS1 set bold+white (1;37) -- Thanks!

Comment: You can mark it accepted, then.

Answer (score 0):

The whole output of ls will be printed in the last **active** color. If `ls` is called without color:

```
$ printf '\e[0;31m color test\n'; /bin/ls
 color test
filea  fileb  filec  filed  filee  filef  fileg  fileh
```

will print the list of files in **red**.

Or, if there is no color change needed for ls, the last color will remain:

```
$ mkdir t1; cd t1; touch file{a..h}
$ printf '\e[0;31m color test\n'; /bin/ls --color -l
 color test
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb 23 01:16 filea
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb 23 01:16 fileb
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb 23 01:16 filec
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb 23 01:16 filed
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb 23 01:16 filee
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb 23 01:16 filef
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb 23 01:16 fileg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb 23 01:16 fileh
```

Still, all in red.

But, as soon as `ls` needs to set a color (and then reset colors to the default used by the console), the color used from then on will be the console default.

```
$ printf '\e[0;31m color test\n'; /bin/ls --color -la
 color test
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Feb 23 01:16 .
drwxr-x--- 7 user user 4096 Feb 23 01:15 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 Feb 23 01:16 filea
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 Feb 23 01:16 fileb
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 Feb 23 01:16 filec
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 Feb 23 01:16 filed
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 Feb 23 01:16 filee
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 Feb 23 01:16 filef
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 Feb 23 01:16 fileg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 Feb 23 01:16 fileh
```

With the first three lines (up to the blue dot) printed in red.